# Extracting a template substitution object from the string

Tags: python, regex, string, string-formatting

Suppose we have a situation like this:

```
>>> a = "test string with %(experiment1)s and %(experiment2)s"
```

Is there a way to extract a list like this?

```
['experiment1', 'experiment2']
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `regex`:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = "test string with %(experiment1)s and %(experiment2)s"
>>> re.findall(r'%\((.*?)\)', a)
['experiment1', 'experiment2']
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also trick Python's formatting routine into finding the keys for you:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return self.setdefault(key, "")

d = MyDict()
dummy = "test string with %(experiment1)s and %(experiment2)s" % d
print d.keys()
```

prints

```
['experiment1', 'experiment2']
```